# Error with Android Gradle plugin 0.13 and android-apt 1.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've just updated my android gradle plugin from 0.12 to 0.13. Moreover I've downloaded gradle 2.1. Then, I tried with android studio 0.8.9 in beta but according http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility I have to use at least android studio 0.8.11 (canary channel). So I've updated my android studio but I have still the problem.

For now, I have to use gradle 1.10 and android gradle plugin 0.12.+ to work

Here the error from AS

`Error:No such property: projectDependencies for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl_Decorated`

**Edit :**

Here is my build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        // works with 0.12.+ (not with 0.13.+)
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        // The latest version of the android-apt plugin
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {  // For Android-ViewPagerIndicator
            url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven"
        }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "http://JRAF.org/static/maven/2"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my gradle-wrapper.properties

```
#Fri Sep 19 17:50:42 CEST 2014
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
# use gradle-2.1-all.zip with android gradle plugin 0.13
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip
```

**EDIT 2 :**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'xxx'
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode xxx
        versionName 'xxx'
    }

    // For more information see
    // @link http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Using-sourceCompatibility-1.7
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('../../KeyStore/debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            storeFile file('xxx')
            storePassword 'xxx'
            keyAlias 'xxx'
            keyPassword 'xxx'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        // Just intern. This is alpha build
        debug {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "FORCE_GOOG_GEO_API", "false"  // can be set to true in debug but not in other buildTypes
            buildConfigField "boolean", "ENABLE_LOG", "true"
            buildConfigField "String", "HOST", "\"xxx\""
            versionNameSuffix '-alpha'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            zipAlign true
        }
        // For customer
        recette {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "FORCE_GOOG_GEO_API", "false"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "ENABLE_LOG", "false"
            buildConfigField "String", "HOST", "\"xxx\""
            versionNameSuffix '-recette'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            zipAlign true
        }
        // PreProd
        preprod {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "FORCE_GOOG_GEO_API", "false"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "ENABLE_LOG", "false"
            buildConfigField "String", "HOST", "\"xxx\""
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            zipAlign true
        }
        // Prod
        release {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "FORCE_GOOG_GEO_API", "false"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "ENABLE_LOG", "false"
            buildConfigField "String", "HOST", "\"xxx\""
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            zipAlign true
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }

    // This is important, it will run lint checks but won't abort build
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}

apt {
    arguments {
        resourcePackageName android.defaultConfig.packageName
        androidManifestFile variant.processResources.manifestFile
    }
}

def GoogPlayServVersion = '5.0.+';
def GsonVersion = '2.2.4';
def LibPhoneNumbVersion = '5.9';
def GreenRobotVersion = '2.2.1';
def OkHttpVersion = '2.0.0';
def OkHttpConnVersion = '2.0.0';
def JacksonCore = '2.4.1';
def JacksonDatabind = '2.4.1';
def JacksonAnnotations = '2.4.0';
def SwitchVersion = '1.3.1';
def CroutonVersion = '1.8.4';
def ActionBarSherlockVersion = '4.4.0';
def ViewpagerIndicatorVersion = '2.4.1';
def PicassoVersion = '2.3.4';
def RoboSpiceVersion = '1.4.12';
def StickyListHeaders = '2.4.1';
def AAVersion = '3.1';

def RobotiumVersion = '5.2.1';

dependencies {
    // Include all jar in libs folder
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Google Play Services
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:$GoogPlayServVersion"

    // Gson
    compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:$GsonVersion"

    // LibphoneNumber
    compile "com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:$LibPhoneNumbVersion"

    // GreenRobot
    compile "de.greenrobot:eventbus:$GreenRobotVersion"

    // OkHttp [We use repackaged version @see https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/967]
    // compile "com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:$OkHttpVersion"
    // compile "com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:$OkHttpConnVersion"

    // Jackson
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:$JacksonCore"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:$JacksonDatabind"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:$JacksonAnnotations"

    // Switch backport
    compile "org.jraf:android-switch-backport:$SwitchVersion"

    // Crouton lib
    compile("de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:$CroutonVersion") {
        // exclusion is not neccessary, but generally a good idea.
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    }

    // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    // The Support Repository (separate from the corresponding library) can be found in the Extras category.
    // compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    // compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:19.1.0'

    // ActionBarSherlock
    compile "com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:$ActionBarSherlockVersion@aar"

    // Android-ViewPagerIndicator
    compile "com.viewpagerindicator:library:$ViewpagerIndicatorVersion@aar"

    // Picasso
    compile "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:$PicassoVersion"

    // Robospice
    compile "com.octo.android.robospice:robospice:$RoboSpiceVersion"

    // StickyList headers
    compile "se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:$StickyListHeaders"

    // Facebook sdk
    compile 'fr.avianey:facebook-android-api:+@aar'

    // android annotations
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"

    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:+'

    // Tests part
    androidTestCompile "com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:$RobotiumVersion"
    compile "com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:$RobotiumVersion"
}
```

Do you know how can I solve this ?

Thx

Comment: Please share your build files and the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: This is the full stackTrace from android-studio and the only change between gradle plugin 0.13.+ and 0.12.+ is the version number. It works with 0.12.+ and not with 0.13.+. I'm not sure the problem is in gradle file but I will update my question with my actual build gradle file

Comment: Shouldn't your `gradle-wrapper` say `distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-all.zip`?

Comment: Yes. See my comment, I use gradle-2.1-all.zip with android gradle plugin 0.13 but with android gradle plugin 0.12 (the version which works), I have to use gradle-1.10-all.zip

Comment: Your module-level build file too, please.

Comment: @ScottBarta I presume you talk about the second build.gradle ? If yes, see my EDIT2

Answer (score 15, accepted):

android-apt 1.3 doesn't seem to be compatible with v0.13 of the Android Gradle plugin. Please use android-apt 1.4 instead:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```