# Android Annotation Error with Android Studio Update 1.0

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-annotations

I am working with `Android Annotations` and today I did the new update for `Android Studio 1.0.`

When I build the project it gave me this error:

```
Error:(40, 0) Could not find property 'processResources' on com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl_Decorated@54335f5.
```

Here is my `build.gradle` file for `my project`:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'


        // the latest version of the android-apt plugin https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt
        // http://stackoverflow.com/a/25939518
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

and this is the `build.gradle` file for `my application`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
// duhet per te shtuar librarine e android annotations ne ccompile time http://joostfunkekupper.com/useful-android-libraries/
// https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/IntelliJIDEA
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "<my package>"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
// https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/FAQ
// https://github.com/DayS/androidannotations/wiki/Building-Project-Gradle
//https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt
apt {// http://stackoverflow.com/a/26284580
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.processResources.manifestFile
        // This should of course be your own package name
        resourcePackageName '<my package>'

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile project(':FreeFlow')
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.7.0'
    compile project(':library')
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile project(':viewPagerIndicatorLibrary')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    apt 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.2'
    compile 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.2'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.5'
    compile 'com.paymill.android:android-sdk:1.2.0'
}
```

`Line 40` where the error happens is in second `build.gradle`:

```
androidManifestFile variant.processResources.manifestFile
```

Has anyone encountered this problem because I couldn't find any solution for this problem

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are some changes to apply with the new version of Android Studio.
See [this wiki page](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Building-Project-Gradle) to get an example of the build.gradle.
Pay attention to this line :

```
androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
```

Comment: Hi yDelouis, I'm not using Android Annotations but i'm facing a similar problem with a custom build.gradle file, would you know were I can find information on all changes on Android Gradle plugin 1.0 ?

Comment: Same problem as PoPy. All answers to this appear to be related to apt and annotations.